# How to schedule a PowerShell script using task scheduler in Windows 2012?

Tags: excel, windows, powershell, server

I am using below PowerShell script to run a macro saved in an Excel file. The Excel is saved in a shared path.

I want to schedule this PowerShell script on a Windows server to run daily. How may I make this script run using task scheduler or any other way? Obviously I do not have excel on Windows server so it throws an error

> Cannot load COM type Excel.Application

It works fine from my local machine because I have MS Office there,

```
# start Excel
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$excel.displayAlerts = $false
#open file
$FilePath = '\\sharedpath\filename.xlsm'
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)
##If you will like to check what is happened
$excel.Visible = $false
## Here you can "click" the button
$app = $excel.Application
$app.Run("Workbook_RefreshAll")
$workbook.save()
$workbook.close()
$excel.quit()
```

Comment: I don't think you can use the `Excel.Application` COM object without Excel. Consider using the [ImportExcel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) module. This doesn't require Excel to be installed.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Ash I tried to modify my script with ImportExcel but I guess to upgrade my server to Windows Management Framework 5.1 first. ImportExcel is not recognised as of now. Is there any alternate?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.